# Kotlin Vertx with Coroutines blocks when trying to call run blocking

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines, vertx-verticle

I am using a third party library which has exposed a callback function. The call back function will be called upon success . The callback function is not a suspend function, but when I trying to make a call inside the non suspend function to return the result of a suspend function which makes IO call using aysnc and await , the call never gets compelted. Below I have come up with a simple code snippet which demonstrates the problem.

```
open class TestVerticle: CoroutineVerticle() {

  override suspend fun start() {

    awaitBlockingExample()

  }

 fun awaitBlockingExample():String {

    val future= async(vertx.dispatcher()) {

        makeSuspendFunCall()
     }
     val result:String= runBlocking(vertx.dispatcher()){future.await()}
     println(" The final Result is $result")
     return result
   }

  suspend fun makeSuspendFunCall():String{
    println("Comming here 3")
    delay(500)
    val resp="Test"
    return resp
  }

}
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle("TestVerticle")
}
```

The program runs fines if I remove the delay function in makeSuspendFunCall, but it will get hung if I add the delay function. I am actually simulating suspend function network call using the delay function here. How can I get result from awaitBlockingExample in this scenario ? I clearly understand that by making awaitBlockingExample as suspend function I can make this work and remove the async and run blocking calls inside. But here awaitBlockingExample (non suspend function) represents a implementation provided by a this party library where its  overridden in our implementation .  For example , guava cache provides a reload function, I would like to override the reload function (non suspend function) and call a coroutine function from the reload method to refresh cache value from database or network call.

Comment: Which kotlin version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `vertx.dispatcher()` uses a single thread as an event loop and `runBlocking` blocks this thread.

Details:

Your `awaitBlockingExample()` function is running on this Vertx event loop thread, because it is triggered from the `suspend start()` function. If you invoke `runBlocking()` this Vertx-thread is blocked and never released. But your other coroutines, e.g. `async()`, now have no thread to do their work.

Solution:

I assume that the invocation of `awaitBlockingExample` from the `start` function happens only in this example. In reality I would assume that the external callback uses its own thread. Then there is no problem at all, because now the external thread is blocked:

```
override suspend fun start() {

    //simulate own thread for external callback
    thread {
        awaitBlockingExample()
    }
}

fun awaitBlockingExample():String {

    val future= async(vertx.dispatcher()) {

        makeSuspendFunCall()
    }
    val result:String= runBlocking(vertx.dispatcher()){future.await()}
    println(" The final Result is $result")
    return result
}
```

BTW: You don't require the `async()` block, you can directly call the `makeSuspendFunCall()` from `runBlocking()`

```
fun awaitBlockingExample():String = runBlocking(vertx.dispatcher()){
    val result = makeSuspendFunCall()
    println(" The final Result is $result")
    result
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I was particularly looking for a solution on how I can make a call to coroutine IO blocking call from a non suspend function. I just simplified my use case in the code snippet. For example , guava cache provides a reload function,  I would like to override the reload function (non suspend function)  and call  a coroutine function from the reload method to refresh cache value from database or network call. We cannot use suspendCoroutine as well since the reload method is not suspend function and inside suspendCoroutine we cannot call coroutine function

Comment: A call of a suspended function from a not suspended one is always blocking. You can use `runBlocking` for that.

Comment: @sedovav  If you see I am using a run blocking in my question, my problem when I am calling  a suspend function from a non suspend function and called suspend function is calling another suspend function ( here in the question delay function) , the entire thread gets blocked and application never recovers

Comment: @DevLoper I have changed my answer and hope it is better now.

Comment: @Rene the answer is now addressing the problem I discussed, but it is not solving it completely. If I use your solution I am getting  below error Exception in thread "main" io.vertx.core.VertxException: Executed from the wrong thread. Context not found for ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 . This is because the suspend function uses the httpclient provided by vertx and default dispatcher does not have the vertx context.

Comment: @DevLoper Then you have to switch the dispatchers. Your blocking function `awaitBlockingExample` must run in another thread. Which should be the default anyway, because the external callback will typically use its own thread. Now you can use the `vertx. dispatcher` for the internal coroutines.  I will adapt my answer, but the point with the httpclient is not in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
override fun start() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result = awaitBlockingExample()
    }
}

suspend fun awaitBlockingExample(): String {
    val response =  makeSuspendFunCall()
    println(" The final Result is $response")
    return response
}

suspend fun makeSuspendFunCall():String{
    println("Comming here 3")
    return suspendCoroutine {
        delay(500)
        val resp="Test"
        it.resume(resp)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin 1.3.0 and above**

```
private val mainScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

fun start(){
        mainScope.launch { 
            val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                //This function will return the result. Return type of the below function will be type of data variable above.
                awaitBlockingExample()
            }
            //use your data result from async call. Result will be available here as soon as awaitBlockingExample() return it.
        }
        //Your function will continue execution without waiting for async call to finish.
    }

 fun awaitBlockingExample():String {
    //Your Logic
   }
```

Hope this will help.